# Magento: Create order in backend and have customer complete payment

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm exploring implementation options in Magento and am wondering if anyone has attempted or found a solution to this scenario...

I would like to be able to setup an order via the Magento backend (add products, set shipping price, etc) then have the customer be able to complete the order by logging into their account and proceeding through the checkout process.

Would be really great if the customer could get an email notification with a link directly to the payment step/checkout.

Is there a public extension that does this or something similar? Is the only option to push the products to a customer's cart then manually notify? Any other approaches on this?

Comment: magento is not provide this type of feature

Comment: Stack Overflow is about programming. This sounds like a request for help in using an application.

Comment: Found exactly what you need, check their pro version https://magecomp.com/magento-email-cart.html

Answer (score 1):

Two possible ways of accomplishing this (assuming that all product are enable in that store)

1. In Admin create new order for that customer and add all items to quote, then under 'Items Ordered -> Action' click 'Move to Shopping Cart' (items will disappear from quote and should appear in the customer shopping cart once log in)
   [image]
2. Create a custom quotation module (or modify new order creation)  that email the customer with a link that will restore the quote on so the customer can complete the transaction

Answer (score -1):

The Cart2Quote extension provides exactly that functionality.